# Applescript: Strange characters ("¬†") replacing space

Tags: applescript

I've got a simple code reading a text file into a list. It's a list of CMYK values in this format: `00, 100, 64, 33`. For some reason, the output is replacing spaces with strange characters... "¬†" (return and dagger?).

So this script:

```
set cmykList to {}
set eachLine to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/cmyk.txt")
repeat with nextLine in eachLine
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        copy (nextLine as text) to the end of cmykList
    end if
end repeat
choose from list cmykList
```

returns:
`00,¬†100,¬†64,¬†33,
00,¬†00,¬†00,¬†00,
100,¬†72,¬†00,
100,¬†35,¬†00,¬†100`

Any ideas on why this is, and how I can avoid this?

The text file is set up like so:

```
00, 100, 64, 33  
00, 00, 00, 00  
100, 72, 00, 18  
100, 35, 00, 100  
00, 16, 100, 00
00, 100, 63, 29
00, 66, 100, 07
03, 00, 00, 32
100, 35, 00, 100
00, 100, 81, 04
04, 02, 00, 45
00, 00, 00, 00
03, 00, 00, 32
100, 35, 00, 100
```

Edit: Resolved this issue doing a find / replace:

```
set cmykList to {}
set eachLine to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/cmyk.txt")
repeat with nextLine in eachLine
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        set theText to (nextLine as text)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "¬†"
        set theTextItems to text items of theText
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
        set theText to theTextItems as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
        copy (theText as text) to the end of cmykList
    end if
end repeat
set chooseList to choose from list cmykList
```

But still very curious as to why this happened in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two characters (ASCII 194 160) are the UTF-8 representation of a Unicode [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) character.

You don't specify the source of your text file but wherever it's coming from is using non-breaking spaces instead of regular spaces. As you found out, you can fix the issue by replacing them with regular spaces when you read the file in.

Answer (score 0):

Your file contains Unicode text in UTF8 encoding. Standard Additions’s `read` and `write` commands (stupidly) use ancient classic-MacOS-era legacy encodings by default, so you need to tell them to use UTF8 explicitly:

```
set eachLine to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/cmyk.txt" as «class utf8»)
```